# Included page doesn't display its full content

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I wanna include a page called group_sharer.html in another page:

[image: this is the page which i'll include in the home page]

```
{% block content %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src='/static/media/js/group_sharer.js'></script>
    <form action="." method="POST" id="my-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="campaign" id="">
            {% for campaign in campaigns %}
                <option value="{{campaign.id}}">{{campaign.title}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
            <option value="test">test</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Ive tried to include it to the home page with

```
 {% include "group_sharer.html" %}
```

but its didn't delivered with its full data

[image: And this is the home page]

What should i do know to implement the data at Group_sharer.html to the home page .

Comment: I doesn't matter bro

Comment: there is no problem with the code but the error is at the the way of the implementation

Comment: at an new page a blank page i tried this line 
 {% include "group_sharer.html" %}
but the data were lost like the results of the second photo

Comment: Yeah, just figured out the actual problem, just trying to work out the solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, the thing that is missing is `campaigns`,

Since you require these you also need to pass this context into the template thats including it.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> An included template is rendered within the context of the template that includes it.

Comment: @BaHaa - No worries, have fun!